Why does React handle a 401 error at updateDehydratedSuspenseComponent?
Problem

In the Developer Tools Network tab, all requests are 2xx success.
I can get Valid data from server

But, 401 error occurs.(this api is not mocked api.)

react-dom.development.js:17497 Uncaught Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at updateDehydratedSuspenseComponent (react-dom.development.js:17497:19)
    at updateSuspenseComponent (react-dom.development.js:17193:16)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:18509:14)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:26927:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:25748:12)
    at workLoopConcurrent (react-dom.development.js:25734:5)
    at renderRootConcurrent (react-dom.development.js:25690:9)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:24504:38)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:256:34)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:225:14)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:534:21)


So, Next.js can't load page.

"use client"

import { apiClient } from "@/util/axios";
import { useSuspenseQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { AxiosResponse } from "axios";

interface PropType {
  params: { sessionId: string };
}

export default function Page({ params }: PropType) {
  const { data: userResponse } = useSuspenseQuery<AxiosResponse<any>>({
    queryKey: ["user", "profile"],
    queryFn: async () => await apiClient.get("/user/profile"),
  });
  console.log(userResponse);
  // const sessionId = Number(params.sessionId);
  // const userData = userResponse.data;
  return <></>;
}



this is page.tsx

export const refreshClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_SERVER,
});

// just retry req with access_token
export const retryClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_SERVER,
});

// req with access_token and re-req with refresh_token when 401
export const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_SERVER,
});

refreshClient.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const refreshToken = Cookies.get("refresh_token");
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${refreshToken}`;
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

retryClient.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const accessToken = Cookies.get("access_token");
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

retryClient.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response.data;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

apiClient.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const accessToken = Cookies.get("access_token");
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
    console.log("req",config);
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

apiClient.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    console.log("success", response);
    return response.data;
  },
  async (error) => {
    const originalReq = error.config as InternalAxiosRequestConfig<any>;
    console.log(error, originalReq);
    if (error?.response?.status === 401) {
      try {
        await refreshClient.get("/auth/token-refresh");
        return retryClient(originalReq);
      } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);


this is axios instances.
As you can see in the console log of this code, there is no error in the response.
I use error.tsx & loading.tsx.
Why does a 401 error appear in the React development environment? All APIs are in this state.
If I use the default axios.get rather than axios instanse, I get an error.tsx screen.
If I use useQuery rather than useSuspenseQuery, I get valid UI and data.

